# If I want to offer a null into an ArrayDeque, how could I do it

Tags: java

Firstly, don't get me wrong. I know there will be `NullPointerException` if the specified element is null in the `ArrayDeque.offer()`. What I mean is that whether there is a viable alternative that is valid grammatically if I want offer something indicates itself is null into it?
The case is below:

> Q: Given the root of a binary tree, check whether it is a mirror of
> itself (i.e., symmetric around its centre).
> Constraints:
>
> 1.The number of nodes in the tree is in the range [1, 1000].
> 2.-100 <= Node.val <= 100

A:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean isSymmetric(TreeNode root) {
        Deque<TreeNode> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        
        if (root != null) {
            queue.offer(root);
            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                int size = queue.size();
            
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    TreeNode node = queue.poll();
                  
                    if (stack.isEmpty() || stack.peek() != node.val) {
                        stack.push(node.val);
                    } else { 
                        stack.pop();
                    }
                    if (node != null) {                     
                        queue.offer(node.left);
                        queue.offer(node.right);
                    }
                   
                }
                if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

But there is something wrong in:

```
queue.offer(node.left);  // offer a null is valid
queue.offer(node.right);  // offer a null is valid
```

So that's my question.

Comment: This very much sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to push a `null`/"empty value"?

Comment: Alright, I have edited my questions again. I just wanna push an element which has a particular meaning so I could make some particular operation. @
Turing85

Comment: Why? What is the use case? Maybe `ArrayDeque` is the wrong data structure. But to be certain, we have to understand the use case.

Comment: Thanks for  reviewing this issue. I have supplemented the case in which I met my question.

Comment: Instead of checking `node != null`, we could check each child individually before inserting them: `final node left = node.left; if (left != null) { queue.offer(left); }`. Not sure of this messes with the overall algorithm though.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use [Null Object Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern). You can define any object (it's better to make it immutable) as `null` value and use it everywhere instead of `null`. E.g. if you use `Jackson`:

```java
public static final TreeNode NULL = NullNode.getInstance();

Deque<TreeNode> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
queue.offer(NULL);

while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
    TreeNode node = queue.poll();

    if(node == NULL)
        System.err.println("null object");
    else
        System.out.println("not null object");
}
```

Another solution, you can use `Optional` instead of `TreeNode` in the `Deque`:

```java
Deque<Optional<TreeNode>> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
queue.offer(Optional.empty());

while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
    Optional<TreeNode> optNode = queue.poll();

    if (optNode.isEmpty())
        System.err.println("null object");
    else
        System.out.println("not null object");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for inspiring me! This is my final-version-algorithm:

```
class Solution {
    static final TreeNode NULL_TREENODE = new TreeNode(101);

    public boolean isSymmetric(TreeNode root) {
        Deque<TreeNode> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
        Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        
        if (root != null) {
            queue.offer(root);
            while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
                int size = queue.size();
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    TreeNode node = queue.poll();
                    if (node != root) {  
                       stack.push(node.val);
                    } 
                    if (node != NULL_TREENODE) {

                        if (node.left != null) {
                            queue.offer(node.left);
                        } 
                        if (node.left == null) {  
                            queue.offer(NULL_TREENODE);
                        }
                        if (node.right != null) {
                            queue.offer(node.right);
                        }
                        if (node.right == null) {
                            queue.offer(NULL_TREENODE);
                        }
                   }
                }
          
                while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
                    if (stack.removeFirst() != stack.removeLast()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

However, it's not a good algorithm for this question, cause it needs much extra memory space by the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ArrayDeque, why not simply use LinkedList addLast Method,

```
public void addLast(E e)
Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
This method is equivalent to add(E).

Specified by:
addLast in interface Deque<E>
Parameters:
e - the element to add
```

Answer (score -1):

**Simple but not so good solution:**

- Use `ArrayDeque<Optional<MyClass>>` with `MyClass` being your class. Then you can add an empty Optional.
- You could also use any other wrapper class for this, and set the contained element null.

**Better solution:**

But to solve your problem better, generally I'd suggest you have special elements, defined as constants, like so:

`static public final MyClass STOP_INDICATOR = new MyClass();`
and MyClass maybe fitted with some special CTOR if it needs more info.

If you then retrieve it and check it, you can even use the *identity* check `a == b` and don't have to use `a.equals(b)`, because it's a constant.

Comment: Nitpick about notation: an `Optional` never contains `null`. It is either "empty" or contains a non-null value. Specifically `get()` can never return `null`. That might be just semantics, but without that distinction `Optional` would be self-defating.

Comment: Thanx for clearing that up. I'll fix it in my answer.